# set boolean value in sqlite android

Tags: android-sqlite

I have column which is supposed to contain the true and false value in db. I understand that they should be in form of 0 and 1. I have an int column "status" but it always returns zero.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                +  VALUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                +  STATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(create_table);

    }
     public int getStatus(String _id,int status)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + STATUS + " FROM "
                    +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + _ID +" =? " , new String[] {_id});
    
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(STATUS));
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

I need to set to true in the case below but `item_status` returns zero everytime. I checked the db and there is NULL in the whole status column.

```
if (success) {
   status = 1;
   int item_status = db.getStatus(fetchId(),status);
   Toast.makeText(this, " item_status " + item_status , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                       

   }
```

Comment: Where's the code that sets the value?

Comment: I am setting it as status = 1;

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement which should not be there. If your app does not crash this means that the onCreate() method does not run because the database and the table already exist and probably the schema of the table is different.

Comment: I removed that and reinstalled the app but the result is still same.

Comment: *I checked the db and there is NULL in the whole status column*. This is impossible because you have defined the column as NOT NULL. This means that the table that you think you have created is not the actual table you have. Try in a clean device.